# listView update doesn't work with static variable

Tags: java, android, listview, runnable, ui-thread

I've got a ListView with a custom adapter. I want to update the data of the ListView. To do so I wrote this function inside the adapter:

```
public void addData(Offer newOffer){
    this.offerList.clear();
    this.offerList.add(newOffer);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My problem now is that when I want to invoke this function outside the UI thread with the following function, which is not situated inside OffersActivity, it does not work:

```
@Override
public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
    final String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OffersActivity.offerAdapter.addData(new Offer("test", message));
        }
    });
}
```

The adapter is a public static variable in OffersActivity. Does anybody has an idea why this is not working?

Bruno

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run `notifyDataSetChanged()` from any thread other than the original UI thread. Do this

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                OffersActivity.offerAdapter.addData(new Offer("test", message));
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Seems you've been faster than me. ^^

Comment: Haha only by a few seconds :)

Comment: The problem is that the function handleDelivery is inside another class ...

Comment: Is there any callback that you can use? What is the `handleDelivery` function part of?

Comment: But what do you need the Handler at the first place? Why not to use an AsyncTask instead if you need to process something in the background and return a result. Easier to handle from my point of view, as `onPostExecute` runs on the UI Thread directly?

Comment: handleDelivery is part of the DefaultConsumer of RabbitMQ.

Comment: You will need to create a callback in your handleDelivery method that is exposed in the activity from where you call the consume method

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do that? And another question if I use for example a BroadCastReciever do I still have to run this on the ui thread?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your method should be name `updateData` instead of `addData` as it doesn't add anything but replace old data with new one.

Then try (assuming your `handleDelivery` method is in your Activity):

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           // NON static variable
                           OffersActivity.this.offerAdapter.addData(new Offer("test", message));
                        }
                    }
```